# Xamarin Android intercept/support intent action

Tags: c#, android-intent, xamarin

I am struggling to figure out, due to lack of knownledge on Android, how to support incoming request for action/extras if my application is or not running.

How to implement it? Where?

So far i am reading around IntentFilter but i am not sure if this is a good starting point.

What i want to accomplish:

- call something like com.my_app.intent.action, from another application, and run an action in my app based on the request action name and extras.
- this should work even if the app is not running(automatically start it, and if it is running)

Thanks in advance and sorry if i can't provide with stuffs i tested because i have no clue where to start or what to search exactly.

Comment: IntentFilter is a right spot... start by going through Google's doc on `Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity` @ http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a look.